# Java Beginner arrays, loops and strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

I have a project due and the details are as follows: write a Java program that holds 6 player's names and reads in and stores his/her best game score and the calculate:

1. Average Score
2. Highest Score
3. Lowest Score

I have coded the following

```
import java.io.*;

public class Assignment2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String greeting = "Hello"; //greetings
        String myName; //string to store names
        int[] scores = new int[7];
        String[] scores1 = new String[7];

        int highest ;
        int smallest;
        int averages;


        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("*** Welcome to the program ***\n"); //displays greetings
        System.out.println(greeting);


        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) // gets 6 names    
        {
            System.out.println("Please type names of players :");
            myName = br.readLine();
            System.out.println( " " + myName);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < scores1.length-1; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("\n\nEnter Score " + (i+1) + ": ");
            scores1[i] = br.readLine();
        }
    }

}
```

I am finding it difficult to display the numbers and so on. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't written any code to print any numbers or calculate any averages.  Start by trying something.

Comment: You need to ask a specific question.  For example, "How do I print the numbers to a file?" or "How do I list the numbers in the console?" or "I expect this to list the numbers in the console, but nothing appears.  What am I doing wrong?"  

Also, people will be more willing to help if your question demonstrates at least some searching has been done.  E.g. "I searched for the error I was receiving and found these 3 links <links>, but I haven't had any luck with them."

http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Think about what the assignment asks. You have 6 player names and each player has more than one (1) score as an average won’t mean much with only one score. You might consider making a Player Class which has a name and an array of scores. This should make things much simpler. As your code shows now, you are only saving ONE score for each player, you need to get multiple (you don’t say how many scores) scores for a player. You are displaying other things with your print statements try that with your numbers.

Comment: Have you thought about a `Player` in terms of what a conceptual player _has_? For example, a player might _have_ a list of the `n` most recent scores (or most recent `Game`s where each `game` _has_ a score). In object-oriented programming you'd create a type `Player` with an attribute for each thing it _has_: `public interface Player { List<Game> getGames(); }`, etc. You can calculate what you need for each `Player` from its attributes.

Comment: I been researching all day reading on this website but have still gotten no further, thats why i decided to make an account and post because i honestly have no idea

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write your code for you.  You won't learn to program is someone else does your programming for you.   But here are some hints.

Hints:

1. "I am finding it difficult to display the numbers and so on."

   You already have written code to display a number!
2. You need to figure out how to convert a string to an integer.  Read the javadocs for the `Integer` class.
3. A simply way to print an array of integers is to use `Arrays.toString(...)`.  Alternatively use a loop.
4. To calculation an average you start by calculating a sum.  (You remember four high school maths lessons?)
5. To find the highest number, you pick a candidate (e.g. the first), test it against all of the others, replacing the candidate if it is not the largest.  It can be done with a simple for loop, a temporary variable and an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is instead of finding the highest and lowest number is to find the index at which those numbers exist. Doing so will allow you to match the highest and lowest numbers to the name. Example names[0] = Fred and numbers[0] = Fred's number. So if Fred got the lowest number, we would keep track of his index (in this case 0) and then display his name with his score at the end of the program.

I suggest reading this answer I recently posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41912197/need-help-displaying-information-from-a-loop/41912486#41912486